# Did you ever train an AI to be a moderator?

Tags: discussion, moderation, robots

Stack Overflow has over 18 million questions not counting the deleted ones. All in all there are 100s of millions of recorded actions of the site (asking, answering, voting, closing, reopening, flagging, ...)

This would make a good basis for training an AI to do some moderator work. 
Did the SE team (or anyone else) ever try that and if so with what outcome?

Comment: There have been several - https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/17/meet-the-bots-that-help-moderate-stack-overflow/

Comment: We have bots helping with spam (which auto-flag as well), and various other bots assisting humans, but AFAIK, none have attempted to make AI mods in the definition of replacing mods.

Comment: We have Martijn Pieters, we don't need AI ....

Comment: @ChrisF: I know there are many bots. But they all are just "normal" programs and not AIs, right?

Comment: @juergend - I don't follow. AIs are just programs acting on data. There's nothing magical about them.

Comment: @ChrisF: Sure they are not magically but different in the way being "made" compared to normal programs.

Answer (score 19):

While bots/AI can be, and have been, written to spot spam, unfriendly language, duplicate answers etc. ultimately the diamond moderators are exception handlers. These bots work because the problem they are solving is well defined and has a definite outcome. Other moderation tasks require more knowledge and awareness than is probably feasible to build into a program.

We're there to do the stuff that *can't* be done automatically, so trying to write a program to that part of our job would be quite complex (to say the least).

I see you're thinking of other moderation activities like closing questions. I'm not aware of any programs that have been written to classify whether a question is off topic or not, or whether it's a duplicate of an existing question. It would be interesting to see if there were any experiments and how successful they've been.

Comment: I guess I did not use the right terminilogy. I did not mean replace a mod. I meant doing some moderation like fror instance closing questions.

Comment: @juergend we don't need AIs for that, we have regular users ;)

Comment: Not nearly enough to keep the system efficient.

Comment: That being said, technically speaking, it would be possible to put together a compound system (dupe hunter, close vote reason finder, heat detector, spam hunter, NAA detector, and whatever other potential issues I've left out) to make an AI moderator (not diamond moderator though). We've already done it for spam, provided more effort and putting it into a ML AI (Smokey is mostly pattern-based, not ML), it could be possible to automate a lot. I vaguely remember a project that automated dupe hunting, actually.

Comment: There was a [kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/predict-closed-questions-on-stack-overflow) 7 odd years ago

Comment: @JonClements I'd forgotten about that.